# Uniform Convergence Proof in Spivak's Calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I have done everything in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S71Yn.png) problem except "conclude that the series does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$". I know something happens at $x=0$  and that $$ \lim_{N \to \infty} f \bigg( \frac{1}{N}\bigg) \geq \frac{1}{4} $$ might be useful, but I am not sure where to go from here. How can this be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f(0)=0$, the limit shows that $f$ is not continuous. Actually the limit likely does not exist; all you are showing is that $f(1/n)\geq1/4$ for all $n$, not that the limit exist. Still, this is enough to show that $f$ is not continuous.

In any case, if the series were to converge uniformly on an interval containing zero, its limit would be continuous in that interval.

Comment: Is that last statement justified by a theorem? I want to prove this as rigorously as possible using only first year analysis knowledge.

Comment: Theorem? No. Just the definition of continuity.

Comment: I'm still not seeing this, could you explain in more detail?

Comment: What does it mean for you that $f$ is continuous at zero?

Comment: $\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists \delta>0$ such that $\left | x \right | < \delta\Rightarrow \left | f(x)-f(0) \right | < \epsilon$

Comment: Exactly. In your case, is even a little simpler, because you know that $f(0)=0$. The fact that $f(1/n)\geq 1/4$ shows that $f$ satisfies the negation of the sentence you wrote.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, so then how does $f$ fail to satisfy the definition of uniform convergence?

Comment: I quote from my answer: "if the series were to converge uniformly on an interval containing zero, its limit would be continuous in that interval".

Comment: Right, that is the statement which I can't see yet. What is the justification for uniform convergence implying continuity?

Comment: It's a basic exercise. In the chapter of Spivak you just supposedly read it is Theorem 2, and more explicitly in the case of series, the Corollary.